# How to retrieve Specific Data from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database, but somewhere it's going wrong.

[Here is the screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dIpR.png)

I want to retrieve all the Question(Question1,Question2,etc) data under "CS102" node and store it in arraylist.
I tried doing it in a few ways:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CreateQuizQuestions").child(code);
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                String QuizName=ds.child("QuizName").getValue().toString();
                String TotalQuestions=ds.child("TotalQuestions").getValue().toString();
                String ques=ds.child("Question").getValue().toString();
                String option1=ds.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
                String option2=ds.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
                String option3=ds.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
                String option4=ds.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
                String correctAnswer=ds.child("CorrectAnswer").getValue().toString();

                GetQuestion getQuestion=new GetQuestion(ques,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer);
                list.add(getQuestion);

                Log.d("Data Values: ","Question:"+list.get(0).question+" Option1: "+list.get(0).option1);
                Log.d("Inner Size Tag","Size of list: "+list.size());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

But somewhere it's going wrong
Please help me in finding the solution

Comment: What's inside Question, Question1...? Do you need only the keys of the nodes or the data inside?

Comment: You are trying to get the data of "Question1", "Question2", etc. But you have to get the value of the nodes inside "Question1", "Question2" named "QuizName" and "TotalQuestions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, you should be able to gather the info of all "Question1" nodes. You will have to do this for each "Question2", "Question3" node. If for example "Question2" node has different children, you won't have to use same number of variables to retrieve the data. Of course you must add another event listener because database reference will be different. If your other question children have same number of children (answer, optrion1, 2,3,4 and question) you can use the `for` loop I have shown you before. Hope this works for you!!!

```
 DatabaseReference  ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CreateQuizQuestions").child("CS102").child("Question1");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists())
                        {
                        

                            
                       String  answer=snapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
                            
                           
                         String  op1=snapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
                         String  op2=snapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
                         String  op3=snapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
                         String  op4=snapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
                         String  q=snapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();                                

                            //GetQuestion getQuestion=new GetQuestion(ques,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer);
                            //list.add(getQuestion);

                            //Log.d("Data Values: ","Question:"+list.get(0).question+" Option1: "+list.get(0).option1);
                            //Log.d("Inner Size Tag","Size of list: "+list.size());                     
                              
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

}

Comment: It's still not working, getting an error:  
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference" 
on the line: String QuizName=ds.child("QuizName").getValue().toString();

Comment: Probably not finding the node... Can you share a pic of the database or share the .json?
I think the issue is on the DatabaseReference

Comment: Now your database looks different, that node "Code" is new, so now to read a particular question, you can use this, i will edit my answer for question1

Comment: I want to store all the data in "Question1" in an object and then add that object into the array list and similarly work for the remaining question as well

Comment: i edited the answer, try it now. But to do what you said, you must create a model with same attributes as a question has on firebase and save it into it's object, then you will be able to save the object as much times as you want on an arraylist with the `for` loop i have shown you before

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try but I have already tried what you said and it didn't worked

Comment: It should be reading at least Question1 nodes, doesnt it?